# Python Qt How to open a pop up QDialog from a QMainWindow

Tags: python, qt, popup, qmainwindow, qdialog

I'm working on a project where I have a Database linked with a Python interface (I'm using Qt Designer for the design). I want to have a delete button from my main window (`QMainWindow`) where, when I'm pressing it, it opens a pop up (`QDialog`) which says

> Are you sure you want to delete this item?

But I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2):

```
def button_click():
    dialog = QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Delete?', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?', buttons = QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok|QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
```

Bind this function to the button click event.

Comment: I have this error when i write your script : 

dialog = QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self.tableViewPatient, 'Delete?', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?', buttons = QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok|QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
    TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
    QMessageBox.information(QWidget, QString, QString, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton): argument 1 has unexpected type 'PySide.QtGui.QTableView'

I guess it may be an error from the self ? (not sure) Can you still help me with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your Qt Designer ui has a main window called "MainWindow" and a button called "buttonDelete".

The first step is to set up your main window class and connect the button's clicked signal to a handler:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.buttonDelete.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonDelete)
```

Next you need to add a method to the `MainWindow` class that handles the signal and opens the dialog:

```
    def handleButtonDelete(self):
        answer = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(
            self, 'Delete Item', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No |
            QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel,
            QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if answer == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            # code to delete the item
            print('Yes')
        elif answer == QtGui.QMessageBox.No:
            # code to carry on without deleting
            print('No')
        else:
            # code to abort the whole operation
            print('Cancel')
```

This uses one of the built-in [QMessageBox functions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#static-public-members) to create the dialog. The first three arguments set the parent, title and text. The next two arguments set the group of buttons that are shown, plus the default button (the one that is initially highlighted). If you want to use different buttons, the available ones can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum).

To complete the example, you just need some code to start the application and show the window:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I get this error : 

TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QMessageBox.question(QWidget, QString, QString, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton): argument 1 has unexpected type 'MyKinectViewer

Comment: @user3369214. My example code is correct (I know, because I've tested it). The first argument of `QMessageBox.question` (which is `self` in my example) must be a Qt widget. I suspect you are attempting to pass an ordinary python object instead, which is why you are getting the error. What is the `MyKinectViewer` class? Without seeing your code, it's hard to diagnose the problem further.

Comment: Well, MyKinectViewer is a QGLWidget... can you help me with this few information ? :s It's a widget which allows me to display a Kinect 3D video

Comment: @user3369214. Your `MyKinectViewer` class is not a subclass of `QGLWidget`. If it was, you wouldn't get that error. You can confirm this by doing `print(viewer.__class__.mro())`, where `viewer` is an instance of `MyKinectViewer`. This will show that it does not inherit either `QGLWidget`, or `QWidget`. It might have an instance of `QGLWidget` (or some other `QWidget`) as an attribute. If it does, pass this widget (or any other widget, such as your main window) as the first argument to `QMessageBox.question`.

Comment: When i print print(self.__class__.mro()), I got this message: [<class '__main__.MyKinectViewer'>, <class 'kinect_viewer.KinectViewer'>, <type 'PySide.QtGui.QMainWindow'>, <type 'PySide.QtGui.QWidget'>, <type 'PySide.QtCore.QObject'>, <type 'PySide.QtGui.QPaintDevice'>, <type 'Shiboken.Object'>, <class 'ui_mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow'>, <type 'object'>]. What does it mean ? (sorry for bothering you that much..

Comment: well... I solved the problem doing this : popUp = QtGui.QMessageBox() then dialog = QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Delete?', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?', buttons = QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok|QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for qt5.6

```
TypeError: question(QWidget, str, str, buttons: Union[QMessageBox.StandardButtons, QMessageBox.StandardButton] = QMessageBox.StandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No), defaultButton: QMessageBox.StandardButton = QMessageBox.NoButton): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'
```

So I changed `self` to `None` in the following code, and it works.

```
def handleButtonDelete(self):
    answer = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(
        None, 'Delete Item', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
        QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No |
        QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel,
        QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
    if answer == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        # code to delete the item
        print('Yes')
    elif answer == QtGui.QMessageBox.No:
        # code to carry on without deleting
        print('No')
    else:
        # code to abort the whole operation
        print('Cancel')
```